# RecyclerView - how can I get a reference to each row's View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using the new `RecyclerView` to replace my existing `ListViews` and ran into the following problem: in the old `BaseAdapter`, I could create a "fly-in" `Animation` for each item inside the adapter by simply applying this `Animation` to the `convertView` and noticing in a `SparseBooleanArray` for which position the `Animation` was already shown.

The `onBindViewHolder()` method which has replaced `getView()` doesn't provide access to any `Views`, nor does the new `ItemAnimator`. Basically I would need to access the root `View` of my `ViewHolder` to apply my own `Animation` to each item.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Every view holder used by the `RecyclerView` has to subclass `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` and this class has a public field called `itemView` which contains the `View` associated with the `ViewHolder`.

```
final View view = viewHolder.itemView;
```

But just in general: Animations work differently in the `RecyclerView`. Essentially you implement them in a separate class called `ItemAnimator`:

```
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new RecyclerView.ItemAnimator() {

    @Override
    public void runPendingAnimations() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateRemove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateAdd(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateMove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i, int i2, int i3, int i4) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateChange(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder2, int i, int i2, int i3, int i4) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void endAnimation(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void endAnimations() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return false;
    }
});
```

In all those callbacks you can access the `View` instance through the public field as I explained above. The `RecyclerView.Adapter` unlike the previous `Adapters` is really just responsible for the data in the `RecyclerView`.

You can also look at [**this library on GitHub**](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/RecyclerViewItemAnimators) which already implements a few different `ItemAnimators`.

Please see the documentation for more information!

Comment: Wow!! Never knew about `itemView`. Really helpful post. +1

Comment: it will be better if viewHolder has a method getAttachedView (or something like this) because all of us, are searching for proper method not for public field. Maybe google make this decision because this give a little bit more performance in the recycleview adapter. But for know this is the correct answer if you want to access view in the viewholder object

Comment: "The RecyclerView.Adapter is really just responsible for the data in the RecyclerView"... that may be the theory, but in practice, the adapter inflates and populates all the views in the item. So it's responsible for the views also.

Comment: @GregEnnis Of course. That's why it's called an `Adapter`, it essentially turns your data into `View`s which can actually be displayed. What I meant with my statement was that that is all an `Adapter` of a `RecyclerView` does. This is in contrast to the `Adapter` of a `ListView` which essentially was responsible for everything that happens in your `ListView`. The `RecyclerView` architecture is much better and reduces the responsibility of its `Adapter` to only doing the thing it was named after.